# ASP.NET MVC How to pass a joined data into view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following code in my controller:

```
public ViewResult Index()
{
    var q = from ci in db.City
            join co in db.Country on ci.CityID equals co.CityID
            select ci;
    return View(q);
}
```

the database are as follow:

```
Table City: CityID, CityName
Table Country: CountryID, CountryName
```

in the index view how do I display both the CityName and CountryName:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CityName)
```

and I can't get it to display CountryName :(

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't work because you're only selecting the city in your query. You need to select both. Using an anonymous object is one way:

```
select new { City = ci, Country = co }
```

You should then be able to access `item.City.Cityname`, `item.Country.CountryName` etc.

Comment: @sophie: Didn't I just give you an example?